# Expand the range of numbers

Tags: java, regex, numbers, expansion

I was trying a solve a issue which is bothering me for a while. I created a small parser that reads an `.ini` file and then stores the data in an `ArrayList`. However, I got stuck with the following snippet:

```
while (!(sCurrentLine.equals("[End]"))) {
    formats.add(sCurrentLine);
    for (int i = 0; formats.size() > 0; i++) {

    }
    sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
}
```

Now this is the place where I have to add values into `formats`, which is of type `ArrayList`.
The values that will be added like this:

```
0900.013-017=LABEL
0900.018-029=LABEL
```

Now the range is in between and I also have to make sure that '0900' and '=label' repeats themselves along with the expansion of numbers, for example:

```
0900.013=LABEL
0900.014=LABEL
0900.015=LABEL
0900.016=LABEL and so on...
```

and store it back in the `ArrayList`.

I don't want to depend upon third-party libraries. Please help me out with this.

Comment: The type should be `List<SomeType>`, not raw `ArrayList`, but other than that it is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: if you had to expand this range 0900.013-017=LABEL what would you do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to parse the range, then loop over the parsed values.  There is some fine tuning to be done but I think this should get you started.

```
    Pattern rangePattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)=(.*)$");
    Matcher rangeMatcher = rangePattern.matcher("0900.13-17=First label");

    if (rangeMatcher.matches()) {

        String prefix = rangeMatcher.group(1);
        int start = Integer.parseInt(rangeMatcher.group(2));
        int end = Integer.parseInt(rangeMatcher.group(3));
        String label = rangeMatcher.group(4);

        for (int r = start; r < end; r++) {
            System.out.println(prefix + "." + r + "=" + label);
        }
    }
```

Create the pattern once and then just get new matchers each time through your loop.

The results:

```
0900.13=First label
0900.14=First label
0900.15=First label
0900.16=First label
```

Comment: This solves the problem for me... Thank you so much sir. I'll change the Matcher part and adjust it with getting the values from text file where the values are being called from..

Comment: great!  Don't forget to upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: I did upvote but it won't accept my vote as i am new bee in this place...lolz.

Comment: just small question.. what if i had to keep leading zero's. Coz those numbers are the values that are calling some line description.